# If we can typecast an Integer object to Object and unbox an Integer to int, why can't we unbox the same object to int?

Tags: java

If we can typecast an Integer object to Object and unbox an Integer to int, why can't we unbox the same Object type to int?

```
Integer i=new Integer(5);
Object p=i;
int s=p;//gives error
```

Comment: You've said that it's an Object, and not every Object can be interpreted as an int. How would it know that it's Ok in this case?

Comment: Consider the code below: if say                                                                
               Object[] o = new Object[3];//Line 1
  o[0] = 12;//Line 2-no error
  int i = o[0]; //Line 3-error-but there was no error while boxing then 
                                 // why while unboxing
  System.out.print(i);

Comment: @Sinha `System.out.print(i);` works is because `print()` takes an `Object` as its parameter. You can pass anything you want to it, and it will call the objects `toString()` method, which (because it's an Integer) will end up printing out the integer in string format.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has no idea that something of type `Object` is actually an integer. To your eyes, you can clearly see that you are assigning an integer and that is converted into an integer object. However, as soon as you assign it to an `Object`, that information becomes lost for the *semantic purposes of the source code*.

It's the same reason why this code would be wrong:

```
Object o = getSomeObject();  // What exactly does it return? We don't know
int i = o;                   // How do you know this will work?
```

The function `getSomeObject()` could return anything. We have no idea if it will be an integer, or a String, or an ArrayList... and therefore we have to assume it is an unsafe conversion. If the above makes sense to you, then you can extrapolate to your example why you can't do the conversion.

Now the part I assume that is confusing you is "I clearly put an integer in there, which is auto boxed into an `Integer` and should be assignable by unboxing!"

... however the rules of the language state that once we do that assignment, we have to treat it as that it could be any object of that type. Since we can't blindly assume that the object is an integer, you need to explicitly cast it.

This also plays a role in going up the hierarchy chain for polymorphism. If you have a parent P, and a child C that extends from P, then we know that:

```
Child c = new Child();
Parent p = c;  // Valid, because c is definitely a Parent
```

but

```
Parent p = new Parent();
Child c = p;   // Can't go down the hierarchy, this is also wrong
```

The same thing is seen in your example. `Integer` is a child of `Object`, that's why we can do

```
Integer i = 5;
Object o = i;
```

and likewise, we can't do it in the reverse

```
Object o = new Object();
Integer i = o;  // Not allowed
```

and because for your example we need to go from `Object -> Integer -> int` (by unboxing), the second step from `Object` to `Integer` is not allowed.

---

Now if you did in fact write code like

```
Integer i = new Integer(5);
Object p = i;
int s = (Integer) p;
```

this would work. In fact, the JVM *at runtime* (via HotSpot) would likely notice exactly what you're doing and convert the above code into:

```
int s = 5;
```

because the JVM is likely smart enough to realize exactly what you as a human realize.

So while you have to write *semantically* correct Java source code (which doing `int i = someObj` is not when the right hand side of the equals side is an `Object`), the compiler will likely be smart enough to inline all of it for you when you run your program.

Comment: Very detailed answer. I would add that the *reason* you can't traverse the hierarchy downward is because more than one class can extend a parent class, and the parent class isn't even necessarily aware that it *has* been extended by a child, much less *which* child class you wanted without an explicit cast. In the simple case of unboxing to a primitive, you could probably have the compiler hazard a reasonable guess, but that wouldn't work generally. There is no reason to add that overhead to the language just so *some* semantically incorrect code can run - usually an undesirable outcome anyway

Answer (score 0):

`Upcasting` is casting to a **supertype** in your case `object`, while `downcasting` is casting to a **subtype** in your case `int`. Upcasting is always allowed, but downcasting involves a type check.

```
Object p=i;
```

Here you are doing `Upcasting` which is always allowed because it make sense that `int is an Object`.

```
int s = p;
```

Here `p` is `object` and you are trying to assign it to subtype `int`, how would the compiler will know that `p-object` is an `int` not a string or double etc. So to solve this your have to do downcasting explicitly like this:

```
int s = (int) p;
```

**NOTE:** Wrong downcasting can throw a `ClassCastException`.